# Where are Websphere database configuration files saved?

Tags: java, database, configuration, websphere

When we create a configuration from Admin Console for database configuration, those details will be saved in resource.xml (i think).

What is path of the that configuration file?

Comment: This information is good to know but you should never really worry about this. It is true that most of the DB, JMS and other resources information is stored in resources.xml. These files exist at multiple scopes (Cell, Node, Servers) depending on where the resources is created. For example, if you create a Data Source at the node level it would be created under the <nodename> directory. Is there any reason why you are interested in this?  THe easiest way to know what hte file is by doing this: Use admin console make a change and click on review and see the file name

Comment: Knowing this is really old a reason for this for me at the moment is buggy beahviour of the Websphere (8.5.5.8) console. Noticed this on three different installations (both standalone and cluster). Having multiple datasources, multiple databases, multiple users per database, everything set up and looking correctly in the console, but some data sources actually using different J2C authentication than configured - resulting in using wrong schema or denying logon attempts. Therefore manual fix of the XML is necessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Close, "resources.xml" is what you are looking for. If you are using a standalone Websphere instance, it is likely something close to this:

```
$WAS_HOME\profiles\PROFILE_NAME\config\cells\CELL_NAME\nodes\NODE_NAME\servers\SERVER_NAME\resources.xml
```

PROFILE_NAME, CELL_NAME, NODE_NAME, should all have your machine name in them by default. SERVER_NAME is configurable but I believe is 'server1' by default.

Sorry I could not be more definite, but it there are a lot of variables at play in websphere configurations.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the previous answer keep in mind that `resources.xml` exist on each of the three levels of configuration: Cell level, node level and server level. Database connection can be defined on all of those levels, according to your design:

```
$WAS_HOME\profiles\PROFILE_NAME\config\cells\CELL_NAME\resources.xml

$WAS_HOME\profiles\PROFILE_NAME\config\cells\CELL_NAME\nodes\NODE_NAME\resources.xml

$WAS_HOME\profiles\PROFILE_NAME\config\cells\CELL_NAME\nodes\NODE_NAME\servers\SERVER_NAME\resources.xml
```

Comment: @Gas,I'll defer to your judgement.

Answer (score 0):

All those who have not found yet should check at cluster level

> /$WAS_HOME/profiles/dmgr/cells/cell_name/clusters/cluster_name/resources.xml